# Can I find another course similar to this UC Berkeley course

Tags: algorithm, recommendation-engine

I have been looking online to learn how the current crop of web applications manage their data, on both the server side and client side.

Like, I'm intrigued by Google Suggest, personal recommendations based on my "likes", etc.

So, while I searched for content where I could learn such data structures and algorithms, I came across this course provided by UC Berkeley - http://extension.berkeley.edu/cat/course460.html

The description of this course matches exactly with what I really want to learn.

> Study the algorithms that provide the
>   power behind many of the most
>   effective Web applications. Where do
>   the phases come from for lists like
>   Google suggests? What techniques can
>   generate personal recommendations? How
>   do social networking, mash-ups, and
>   mixed-media sites select and
>   categorize similar groupings of binary
>   content? In this course, you gain a
>   solid understanding of current
>   algorithms and data structures for
>   search, recommendations, groupings,
>   classifications, and combinations of
>   classifiers.

However, there seems to be no way to find more details about this course.

Can someone here help me find a book / online course / site where I could learn more on this subject ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rex Griffiths and I just launched a video podcast about all this stuff this week.  You can find it over at http://StatCasts.com.  We should bring along the funny as well as teach something.  You can follow us on twitter ([@StatCastsCom](http://twitter.com/StatCastsCom)), where we try to link to cool things we're seeing on this front in real time, or just go to the show.  We'll have a lot of links for other people's stuff.  Plus, Rex and I are both active developers and have quite a bit of open source software that we give away for this kind of thing.

There is the [Stanford Course on Machine Learning](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1) which is really interesting, but a little hard to follow without some of their offline discussion.

Outside of courses, you could look at software packages or books and the communities that surround them.  They tend to fill in the gaps about this sort of thing.  So, here's a list of some what's out there:

- [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/), a machine learning library for [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).  There's a [Manning book](http://www.manning.com/owen/) out on this as well.  This is a good solution if you want to learn how to do this stuff with Big Data.
- [Modeling with Data](http://modelingwithdata.org/about_the_book.html), a great book by Ben Klemens who works at the Brookings Institute and explains a really good foundation for this kind of thing.
- [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and a book called [Data Mining](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/book.html).  This is a great way to get involved without getting lost.  Weka has an easy-to-use interface that isn't much harder than a spreadsheet to use.
- The [R language](http://www.r-project.org/) is an amazing place to go for this kind of thing.  You'll usually find anything analytical you want to do in this package.  I have a few books kicking around here for that.  [The R Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470510242) is my favorite, though it's a bit expensive.
- [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is the GNU response to [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) (commercial software).  They both have incredible resources behind them.

I think Ben Mabey put together a pretty good [pinboard](https://pinboard.in/u:bmabey/t:machine_learning/) full of good teaching links for this kind of thing.

Finally, my stuff is [Fathom](https://github.com/davidrichards/fathom), an open source framework for solving these kinds of problems and http://openmobi.us, a website that implements the Fathom library for people that want to get straight to it.  With those projects, I'm trying to make it easy for people to get involved with building their own models and using them for their businesses or education.

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer. Thank you very much for your help. However I would like to keep the question open for a couple of days more for the community. :)

Comment: Good idea.  This is the kind of thing that can collect some really good answers.  I'd love to hear what other people have found.  I found a new-to-me library since I posted that I'd like to look at: http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/ as well as the really cool wekinator http://wekinator.cs.princeton.edu/